# Counting the number of trials.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> An urn contains $5$ boxes. Each box contains $5$ balls of different colors
>   red, yellow, white, blue and black. Rangeela wants to pick $5$ balls of 
>   different colors ,a different colored ball from each box .If from the first 
>   box in the first draw, he has drawn a red ball and from the second box 
>   he has drawn a black ball , find the maximum number of trials that are 
>   needed to be made by Rangeela to accomplish his task if a ball 
>   picked is not replaced .

$\color{green}{a.)\ 12 }\\
b.)\ 11 \\
c.)\ 20 \\
d.)\ 60 \\
$

As the Ball need to be last place I though I would be $5+5+5=15$

But it is not given in options so I am confused.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is 3+4+5 = 12

Two balls have already been found. When picking the third one, we just need any NEW color. Worst case scenario is we pick red and black, before picking a new color. So that's 3.
The next one, worst case is picking all the previous 3 colors before finding a new color. So 4 balls are picked.
Finally, worst case scenario for the last one is we pick every one we already have, 4, then the last one needed. So 5.
3+4+5=12

Comment: I agree with Jay!