# Ball and boxes (An urn contains 5 boxes)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

An urn contains 5 boxes. Each box contains 5 balls of different colors red, yellow, white, blue and black. Rangeela wants to pick 5 balls of different colors ,a different colored ball from each box .If from the first box in the first draw, he has drawn a red ball and from the second box he has drawn a black ball , find the maximum number of trials that are needed to be made by Rangeela to accomplish his task if a ball picked is not replaced.

Its given the answer is 12. But I don't understand why the balls can't be picked up again from the first two boxes.(When 3 balls is picked from the third box,why can't the new color box be again picked up from the first two boxes( Eg : The first 2 balls from third box be black and red, then the third ball be white, why can't white color be again picked up from the first two boxes, in that case asnswer shouldn't be 12))

Comment: It says "a different colored ball from each box", so having drawn red from box $1$, he can't pick another color from box $1$, and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of trials.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423865/counting-the-number-of-trials)